# JPA 2.0 Sub select in JPA criteria query

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0

How to write criteria query with subquery (use CriteriaBuilder construct method)?

```
  select t1.id,
       t1.name,
       (select count(t2.id) from table_name_2 t2 where t2.t1_id = t1.id) as   some_count
    from table_name t1
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

The same way you wrote it, but instead of table_name you use entity class names.